# Primeng Tabview Stack option

Tags: angular, primeng

I know in Primeng Tabview if the screen is too small the tabs if you swipe; however there is no indicator to a user that this is an option.

I also know there is the scrollable property that displays an arrow but that displays all the time.

Is there a way to allow Tabview to stack if the screen is too small? Or only display the arrows if the screen is too small?